# Drawing rectangles that fill up with gradient depending on the value

Tags: java, android

I want to have three separate rectangles that would fill up with gradient. Depending on the value X the gradient would be placed differently. For example if value X = 75 the gradient would be 75% green and 25% red. I wanted to know if there is any library or a method that would allow me to do this in java (android studio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement this, you could use [LinearGradient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient) for the gradient and then create a custom view with methods allowing you to change the layout of the gradient.

```
public class GradientView extends View {

     Paint paint;
     LinearGradient gradient;
     int[] colors = [Color.RED, Color.GREEN];

     public GradientView(Context context, int gradientHeight) {
          super(context);
          paint = new Paint();
          setGradientHeight(gradientHeight);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setShader(colorGradient);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    }

    public void setGradientHeight(int height){
        colorGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height * 0.01 * super.getHeight(), colors, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        paint.setShader(colorGradient);
        invalidate();
    }
 }
```

Haven't tested the code, but it should certainly work something like this.